# Syntax Error in Python with Print

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a python newbie and I am still getting used to the language. Python giving me a syntax error:

```
File "align.py", line 274
    print dic1 = return (traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[0], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic) 
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

These are the lines the error is referring to. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

```
print dic1 = return (traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[0], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic) ##checks direction 1
print dic2 = return (traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[1], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic) ##checks direction 2
print dic3 = return (traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[2], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic)
```

This is the method signature for this code:

```
def trackback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, curr_tup, A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic)
```

Comment: Those lines are not even close to proper Python syntax.

Comment: What do you *intend* to print?

Comment: Why do you expect an assignment *of a `return` statement* **in a `print`** to work? That is not valid Python syntax. What did you expect to happen here?

Comment: @muffinbacon - I mean, each of those lines has a print statement, an assignment statement, _and_ a return statement all smashed on to one line.  Each of those should be on its own line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to mix 3 separate statements in one:

- A print statement (`print xxx`)
- A variable assignment (`dic1 = xxx`)
- A return statement (`return xxx`)

You can only have one of the three on a single line. First figure out what you want your program to do, then pick whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you would like to do with that code.

Anyway, I think that this way you'll get what you want:

```
dic1 = traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[0], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic
dic2 = traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[1], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic
dic3 = traceback_global(M_direction, Ix_direction, Iy_direction, tempList[2], A_scoreDic, B_scoreDic, dic) + dic

print dic1
print dic2
print dic3
```

The return statement will be used inside your `traceback_global` function to assign the value returned by the function to the variables dic1, dic2 and dic3.